# How to get the sheet name using GetOpenFilename in VLOOKUP

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this code down below to use a VLOOKUP in another file that you select using the `GetOpenFilename`. I want `shtName` to be the name of the sheet in the file that you select, but whenever I step through it, it is always the name of the sheet that I am working in and putting the VLOOKUP in.

I have `shtName` in my VLOOKUP and it doesn't show anything when I step through it. `X` shows the filename and path, but `shtName` right after shows nothing. But my VLOOKUP ends up working anyway and it puts the sheet in the formula.

Why is that? I want to be able to do it myself and so I know I get the sheet name from the file you are selecting.

```
Dim iRet As Integer
Dim strPrompt As String
Dim strTitle As String

' Promt
strPrompt = "Please select the last Kronos Full File before the dates of this HCM Report." & vbCrLf & _
    "This will be used to find the Old Position, Org Unit, and Old Cost Center." & vbCrLf & _
    "For example, if the date of this report is 7-28-17 thru 8-25-17, the closest Kronos Full File you would want to use is 7-27-17."

' Dialog's Title
strTitle = "Last Kronos Full File for Old Positions"

'Display MessageBox
iRet = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbOK, strTitle)

Dim LR As Long
Dim X As String
Dim lNewBracketLocation As Long

X = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", _
    Title:="Choose the Kronos Full File.", MultiSelect:=False)

MsgBox "You selected " & X
'Find the last instance in the string of the path separator "\"
lNewBracketLocation = InStrRev(X, Application.PathSeparator)
'Edit the string to suit the VLOOKUP formula - insert "["
X = Left$(X, lNewBracketLocation) & "[" & Right$(X, Len(X) - lNewBracketLocation)

shtName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).name

LR = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row



Range("T2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($E2,'" & X & "]shtName'!$B$1:$AP$99999,15,0)"
Stop
Range("T2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("T2:T" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Stop
Range("T2:T" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
Stop
Range("U2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($E2,'" & X & "]shtName'!$B$1:$AP$99999,41,0)"
Range("U2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("U2:U" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range("U2:U" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
Range("V2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($E2,'" & X & "]shtName'!$B$1:$AP$99999,18,0)"
Range("V2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("V2:V" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range("V2:V" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Comment: You set `shtName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).name` which means `shtName` is the name of the first worksheet within the currently open and active workbook. So if you want `shtName` being something else than that you need to set it instead.

Comment: Ah I thought that the GetOpenFilename would be the active one once I did that. Alright. What would you recommend for getting the sheet name? Can I activate the file from GetOpenFilename or something?

Comment: I recommend: Open the file with [Workbooks.Open Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel) get the worksheets name and close it. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should give you the worksheets name out of a file

```
Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="YOUR_FILE_PATH", ReadOnly:=True)

Dim shtName As String
shtName = wbk.Worksheets(1).Name
wbk.Close
```

Note: We can open the workbook in read only mode if we don't plan to change anything.

---

Additionally I recommend (for a good code following good practices):

- Always specify a worksheet.
  Eg for **every** `Range("")` like `Worksheets("YourSheetName").Range("")`
  Or use `With` statements:

  ```
  With Worksheets("YourSheetName")
      .Range("A1").Value = 5   'recognize the starting full stop referring to the with statement
  End With
  ```
- Same for **every** `Rows`, `Columns`, `Cells`, etc.
- Avoid using `.Select`, `.Activate` and `Selection.` at all.
  (there are many tutorials out there in the Internet how to avoid them).
- Use `Option Explicit` and declare **all** your variables before use.
  (avoids many issues, especially typos).

Comment: I see. Awesome I will check that out. Working out another issue real fast first : )

Comment: Yeah I usually start my code by recording a macro, and that uses selection constantly and I just don't want to go through and change it all. I am pretty new at this and trying to do a lot for my job. I am trying to go as fast as I can because it takes a while trying to figure it out as I go. I am the only one who will be looking at the code but I have been trying to improve it as I go. Thank you for the pointers.

Comment: Could you tell me why my VLOOKUP works with or without having shtName in it where it is in my original post? I can take it out and it doesn't effect it at all. I can even type random letters there and it didn't effect it at all.

Comment: @Robillard Can you tell me how your VLOOKUP looks like in that specific cell where you say it is working? If you want the value of the variable use something like this `"=VLOOKUP($E2,'" & X & "]" & shtName & "'!$B$1:$AP$99999,15,0)"` otherwise `shtName` is not recognized as a variable within that string.

Comment: The recommendations were not meant to make the code look nicer but it is much easier to avoid a lot of coding issues (especially as a beginner) if you respect these points I mentioned. It looks like a bunch of work at first but it will make your life much easier following a good practice. Macro recorder is a good tool to get an idea of a code, the code it produces works but it is really bad.

Comment: haha yeah I have noticed about the recorder. I am going to be keeping your post open and trying to write better following it.

As for the VLOOKUP, it looks like it should then with the full filepath and with with the worksheet name. I just didn't think it would pull the worksheet name. I am just wondering because what if I needed to go to the second worksheet? That is kind of why I was trying to pull the worksheet name in the first place. It looks like it pulls straight to the first worksheet so I would have to make the "X" direct to the second worksheet before the VLOOKUP happens I think?